# Go to Default SMS Application settings through my Application

Tags: android, notifications, sms, settings, application-settings

Is it possible to go to the default SMS Application settings page through my application?
For example I have a button in my app, when it is clicked it must redirect user to default sms application settings so that user can close the notifications which is required in my application.

I have tried this code:

```
 Intent a = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
            a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(a);
```

Now this will redirect me to All applications page but i want to redirect user to default sms application directly
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try that. I hope it will work.
This is just the way to go to setting page of application. For that you must know the package name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: But sir how can i go to default sms settings? because i don't know that which sms application the other user would be using as their default one

Comment: you can set type but for that you must know the package name, right now its redirecting to the current application.    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");